# django makemigrations doesn't recognize new model

Tags: django, migration

I created a new model with `manage.py startapp supplier` edited some stuff in the views, url and models. Now I execute `python manage.py makemigrations` but django doesn't recognize my new model "No changes detected" it says

Comment: Did you add your app name in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list in `settings.py` ?

Comment: no, will do that :)